# Assert dependency has been called with Sinon

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I am trying to assert against if a dependency has been called.

My code example is

```
export default class vehicle {
private builder: CarBuilder;

constructor() {
  this.builder = CreateCar(); <- factory return fake data
}

createBmw(model) {
  return this.builder.validate(model); <- test this line has been called
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
it("createBmw method should make call to validate", () => {
  //not sure if this the correct way?
  const carBuilder = new carBuilder();
  const builder = sinon.stub(carBuilder, "validate");

  const sut = new vehicle();
  sut.createBmw("5 series");

  expect(builder).to.be.called;
});
```

Comment: How did you import `CreateCar` factory function?

Comment: in my main class i have imported  { CreateCar } from "../builders/carBuilder"

Answer (score 0):

Sinon can't stub standalone function. The `CreateCar` factory function for your case. So, you should use [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) to do that. We need [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to construct our seams.

E.g.

`vehicle.ts`:

```
import { CarBuilder, CreateCar } from './builders/carBuilder';

export default class Vehicle {
  private builder: CarBuilder;

  constructor() {
    this.builder = CreateCar();
  }

  createBmw(model) {
    return this.builder.validate(model);
  }
}
```

`builders/carBuilder.ts`:

```
export interface CarBuilder {
  validate(model): void;
}

export function CreateCar(): CarBuilder {
  return { validate(model) {} };
}
```

`vehicle.test.ts`:

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('68197110', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const carStub = { validate: sinon.stub() };
    const CreateCarStub = sinon.stub().returns(carStub);
    const Vehicle = proxyquire('./vehicle', {
      './builders/carBuilder': {
        CreateCar: CreateCarStub,
      },
    }).default;
    const sut = new Vehicle();
    sut.createBmw('5 series');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(carStub.validate, '5 series');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  68197110
    ✓ should pass (1481ms)


  1 passing (1s)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |   83.33 |      100 |      50 |   83.33 |                   
 68197110          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  vehicle.ts       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 68197110/builders |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 |                   
  carBuilder.ts    |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 6                 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```